# Writing first interpreter with Python - choice of OCaml language

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, ocaml, interpreter

I am reading code for Scheme interpreters with Python by P. Norvig, and I would like to try to write an interpreter with Python. This is properly the subject of post: [What language can a junior programmer implement an interpreter for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446065/what-language-can-a-junior-programmer-implement-an-interpreter-for-it). However, I am strongly interested in learning OCaml for a long time, and it could be the right occasion if I make up my mind for OCaml.

Should I expect much effort to implement a Python interpreter of OCaml language? This is just a personal project and my aim (besides learning OCaml), is mainly to practice the things I have read on compilers and interpreters.

If OCaml is not suited, what would you personally advice?

Could you hint at good ref for OCaml (or even: writting an OCampl parser/interpreter).

##  EDIT

What about Lua / Ruby / BASIC ? (because I want to learn those as well)

Thanks and regards

Comment: Are you proposing to write a Python interpreter in OCaml or an OCaml interpreter in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start reading SICP of Gerald Sussman from MIT, and in the 4th chapter you will build a few interpreters for different purposes. In the 5th chapter you will build compilers.

Also, try reading the source code of GNU/Emacs, which has a nice interpreter of elisp.

Also, you can subscribe to Compilers course of coursera.org, ad build there a quite complex interpreter.

I suggest you to write an interpreter of scheme/lisp, because you do not have to cope with parsing, and python works exactly the same as these.

Comment: For compilers purposes, it is hightly recommendable to subscribe in the same time to the course of Automata with Ullman, because in compilers building you use almost everything what is learnt in the course of automata...

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be saying you want to create an OCaml interpreter in Python (not a Python interpreter in OCaml, right?).  OCaml per se is too large a language to choose for an educational project, in my opinion.  I would choose a much smaller language.  That's why Scheme is a good choice--the core language is quite small.

With OCaml you also have type inference, which is excellent to learn about but again is a rather large topic.

For something small and somewhat ML-ish you might start with the untyped lambda calculus.  It's an extremely common test case.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a good introduction to the semantics underpinning of OCaml (a bit of the theory), you should have a look at the book [Using, Understanding, and Unraveling
The OCaml Language](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~remy/cours/appsem/) by Didier Rémy.

Writing an implementation of the full OCaml language would be quite some work, but writing an implementation of a reasonable subset of it is doable, for example, as a semester project.

Given than ML languages are very good at symbolic manipulations (interpreters, compilers, analysers, proof checkers...), it is probably more fun to write a Python implementation in OCaml than an OCaml implementation in Python -- which may explain some confusion around your question.

Answer (score 0):

[How to write an interpreter (in Python)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h1mM7VwNGo)

This is a video I made a while ago, after giving a similar talk at a local Python meetup. In the video I implement a small functional language in Python in under an hour. This might be a good place to start .